# Array list not getting split properly

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, split

The value
**ALL||test > test's done> test's done again's done||test > test's done> test's done again's done 2**
is an array list

what i want to do is have a list separated by ||

so the first element is :

```
ALL
```

second:

```
test > test's done> test's done again's done
```

last:

```
test > test's done> test's done again's done 2
```

code i wrote:

```
String record1 = record.toString();
        String[] parts = record1.split("||");
        
        for (int i = 1; i <= parts.length; i++) {
              System.out.println(parts[i]);
            }
```

What i'm getting is each letter by itself and at the end a `]` character which is unwanted as well.

Comment: You have to split by `"\\|\\|"`

Comment: It’s in an arraylist? What does this mean? Is there a single element? Are there multiple elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split by using the following code:

```
    String [] parts = record1.split("\\|\\|");
```

Also, the code written above won't work as the loop is running from 1 to parts.length instead of 0 to parts.length-1.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is a [metacharacter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) and therefore, you need to escape it using a `\`. Since `\` itself is a metacharacter, you need another `\` to escape the `\`. Thus, you need to use `\\|\\|` as the regex.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] parts = "ALL||test > test's done> test's done again's done||test > test's done> test's done again's done 2"
                .split("\\|\\|");
        for (String s : parts) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
ALL
test > test's done> test's done again's done
test > test's done> test's done again's done 2
```

Another problem with your code is that the range of your loop counter is `1 to length_of_ the_array` whereas the indices of a Java array are in the range of `0 to (length_of_ the_array - 1)`. Therefore, if you want to access the elements of the array using their indices, your code should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(parts[i]);
}
```